# Sending a file to a device that is connected through a serial port

Tags: c#

I have a device that is connected to my computer via USB. I'm trying to send a text file, precisely .CSV, to that device, that device can read .CSV files so all I need to do is get a physical copy of that file to that device.

I have been struggling with this problem for 2 days now, I have read similar problems, but all of them read the file and then send the content of the file, not an actual physical copy of it.

```
public SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3", 1000000, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

private string[] message = {"a", "b", "u"};
private int currentMessage = 0;
private string output;
```

```cs
if(!com.serialPort.IsOpen)
{
    com.serialPort.Open();
}

while (currentMessage < message.Length)
{
    com.serialPort.Write(message[currentMessage]);
    currentMessage++;
}

    com.serialPort.Write(output);

    currentMessage = 0;

while (currentMessage < 30)
{
    Debug.Log(com.serialPort.ReadLine());
    currentMessage++;
}
```

This is the result that I'm currently getting:

Transfer terminated. Reason: received unrecognized START command
(received 0 chunks)

Any help/criticism is appreciated.

Comment: That's a very bizarre baud rate.  Are you absolutely sure that's the speed your device communicates at?

Comment: Baud rate ought to be okay if SerialPort.ReadLine returns "received unrecognized START command".  But clearly it is not just a file, the device uses a protocol with a START command.  That requires reading the manual.

Comment: What do you mean by "actual physical copy of it"? What do you think it would be the difference between sending the contents of a file and sending a "physical copy" of a file?

Comment: @SamAxe It's a bizarre baud rate, but the device doesn't communicate at any other speed.

Comment: @istepaniuk Well, the difference is that if I send a string with the information that's in the file, the devices code will break, because it's expecting a .CSV file not a string, but if I send a file then the code will work just fine. I have already tested this using TeraTerm.

Comment: @HansPassant The device doesn't have a manual, it's a prototype, but I have tested this behaviour using TeraTerm which allows me to transfer a .CSV file directly. Maybe you have some insight on how the Transfer function works in TeraTerm? Sending an array of bytes or chars results in the same error.

Comment: @FlasH The problem with this description is that a CSV file *IS* a string. When you send a CSV "file" in TeraTerm, speed aside, it would be exactly equivalent as typing its contents into the terminal by hand. There might be some other things you are missing that causes differences. Among other things, it could be different line endings (CR vs CRLF) or that your hardware is expecting flow control (hardware or XON/XOFF codes). You could also use another terminal connected in place of your hardware to inspect/compare/debug your communication.

Comment: Moreover, the code that you provide is incomplete. It clearly sends "abu" and then nothing else because `output` is not initialized, then prints the response.

Comment: @istepaniuk I have left out the code that actually fills out the `output` string, but that shouldn't be the problem, because I do check if the output string is filled out correctly. "a, b, u" are a set of commands which the connected device reads and then enables certain functionality. I'll look into line endings and also flow control. Thank you for taking time out of your day to help me!